# can we add more class selector to $(this)?

Tags: jquery

Here is the example:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
   <span id="span1"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#div1').click(function () {
  $(this + "#span1").css("background-color","red");
});
```

I have tried this but it's not working.
Any help and suggestions are welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: Tedious way `$('#'+this.id+' #span1').css("background-color","red");` :P

Comment: id is unique why bother doing many things when `$("#span1").css("background-color","red");` is enough?

Comment: This code was just for example i have a nested html which has some class elements too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code `this + "#span1"` outputs like `[object HTMLDivElement]#span1` which will not select any element so nothing would happen with your code.

---

To get element within the clicked context pass `this` context as the second argument in jQuery.

```
$('#div1').click(function () {
  $("#span1", this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

---

**FYI :**  Since both are `id` selector and `id` are unique `$("#span1")` is enough for your code.

---

**UPDATE :** So if there are multiple elements you should use the class instead otherwise only first element with the `id` get selected.

```
$('.div1').click(function() {
  $(".span1", this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```js
$('.div1').click(function() {
  $(".span1", this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <span class="span1">1</span>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <span class="span1">2</span>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <span class="span1">3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Will check your solution and will let you know.

Comment: @Gol.D : `$('.div1').click(function () {
  $(".span1", this).css("background-color","red");
});`